# Get warning message to DataFrame in loop

Tags: python, loops

I'm doing a parameter optimization problem, for example:

```
for i in range(10):
    gini = modelABC(order = i+1).fit().gini
```

But sometimes it will show a warning, for example "ConvergenceWarning: Optimization failed to converge". So I want to have an example result like this:

| i | Gini | Note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 35% |  |
| 2 | 40% | ConvergenceWarning |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 10 | 42% |  |

Please tell me what to do.

I have searched on google but no satisfactory answer

Answer (score 0):

In python you can choose to turn warning or a part of them in exceptions with a warning filter from the warnings library. [Documentation here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html)

Here a short example :

```
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
    # Cause all warnings turn to exceptions
    warnings.simplefilter("error")

    for i in range(10):
        try :
            gini = modelABC(order = i+1).fit().gini
            print("Execute without warning for i=",i)
        except :
            print("Execute with warning for i=",i)
```

If you prefer you can just check the number of warning in the warnings registry :

```
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
    # Cause all warnings to always be triggered.
    warnings.simplefilter("always")

    for i in range(10):
        gini = modelABC(order = i+1).fit().gini

        if (len(w) == 1) :
            #clear warnings registry
            w.clear()
            print("Execute with warning for i=")
        else :
            print("Execute without warning for i=")
```

Hope it helps you.